# Multiple form inputs, how to submit them and save to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, forms

I have a photo upload system that allows a user to upload any amount of photos they want, then I allow them to add a description to each photo and then publish the photos. I have this going, partially. Also I submit the forms with jQuery. Now what I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to do is to send each and every form element through to my php file, and then update each photo to have the description.

```
<form class="upload-results-form" rel="<?php echo $albumID?>" action="javascript:return false;">
<textarea class="description" name="photoID1"></textarea>
<textarea class="description" name="photoID2"></textarea>
</form>
```

Now that's about the idea of how I have it setup, except there could be one textarea or 20 of them.

To try to save and publish these, I am using jQuery like this:

```
$("body").on("submit", ".upload-results-form", function(){

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/add/photos_publish.php",
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){


    }
    });



});
```

So how could I have my php go through each texarea form and save the description for that photoID?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JQuery Ajax doesn't automatically build the POST data for you.  So, you have to build this yourself.  You can either create a JSON object and submit that (and then use `json_decode` in PHP), or you can create *urlencoded* form data and just get the regular `_POST` array in PHP.

```
var _photoID1 = $('#my_form_id').find('input[name="photoID1"]').val();
var _photoID2 = $('#my_form_id').find('input[name="photoID2"]').val();
```

### JSON method:

```
var data = { photoID1 : _photoID1, photoID2 : _photoID2 };

$("body").on("submit", ".upload-results-form", function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: data,
     url: "ajax/add/photos_publish.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){  }
   });
});
```

For this method, you might want to add a header to set `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

### Form POST method:

```
var post_data = "photoID=" + encodeURIComponent(_photoID1)
                + "&photoID2=" + encodeURIComponent(_photoID2);

$("body").on("submit", ".upload-results-form", function(){
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     data: post_data,
     url: "ajax/add/photos_publish.php",
     cache: false,
     success: function(html){  }
   });
});
```

Both ways will get you your data to the server.

(Above code not fully debugged, but basically right.)